# Internal SATA hard disk to USB 2.0

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have 3 internal SATA HDD's - 500GB, 1 TB, 2TB respectively.

I am wondering whether it is possible/are there any devices that I can use in which I can plug in any of my HDD and make it work. Please suggest devices that can run on 220V preferably.

System specs are as below

1. i5 2500
2. 8 GB DDR3
3. ZOTAC ASUS gtx 670 AMP EDITION 2GB
4. CORSAIR 850W
5. AOC e2795VH monitor

The graphics card I am using eats up space in such a way that I only have two ports at my disposal - one of them is being used for HDD which has OS installed in it and the other slot has a 2 TB HDD.

Comment: I don't understand. "You want to plug in a hard drive and make it work?" Do you mean you're after an E-Sata drive? Or that you've run out of SATA ports and need a solution for adding more?

Comment: You should just use external USB 2.0 enclosers they are very cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a bit lenghty, but to say in short, buy a case in which you can fix your internal hdd. the case will have a plug and a usb. connect and use. More explanations [here](http://lifehacker.com/253847/alpha-geek-turn-an-old-hard-drive-into-an-external-drive)

Comment: Thanks!!! I got what I am looking for in Newegg.com
However, is it wise to run two internal hard drives together or should I only look for devices which support one harddisk at a time?

Comment: Keep the HDD which contains OS as internal, and convert the other two as external because two internal makes your system indexing slower (i.e) it will take more time when you search for a file